# Add reverse IN clause to db API

Tags: views, database, privatemsg

I need to add **IN** clause while implementing **hook_views_pre_execute**

But it's not the regular **IN** added like the next line

> {table1}.col1 IN (val1, val2)

```
$query->condition('author', array($user->uid), 'IN');
```

Wanted to add reverse

> {val} IN ({table1}.col1, {table2}.col2)

```
$query->condition($user->uid, array(pm_message.author, pm_index.recipient), 'IN');
```

But the query takes the fields as values not column names

Is it possible to be added in drupal

Simply I need to get messages where the user is the author or the reciever in [privatemsg](https://www.drupal.org/project/privatemsg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's (arguably) non-standard, so you'll need a `where`.

For example,

```
$query = db_select('foo');
$query->where(':val IN ({table1}.col1, {table2}.col2)', array(':val' => $user->uid));
```

will get you

```
SELECT 
FROM 
{foo} foo
WHERE  (:val IN ({table1}.col1, {table2}.col2))
```

(with `:val` replaced by `$user->uid`).